# SSRS - Display header through subreports by using tablix?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a main report containing 5 subreports. My ultimate goal is to have a header with an image in it to only show within 2 of the subreports. I'm trying to achieve this by using a tablix and putting all of my subreports into the tablix on the main report, and putting the image into the header of the tablix and using a hide/show query based on subreport name.

The problem is that when I put the subreports into the tablix and upload it to CRM it won't display at all. If I remove the tablix the subreports will run and display perfectly. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here or an alternative if there is an easier way to achieve what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Tablix with a row above the detail group so it shows a header for each line is a good idea, but creating the header within the actual report and adding a new parameter which tells the report whether to show the header or not is a good idea as well. If you go for the second, you can set a default value to show or hide the header depending on your needs. 
I use to create a param called "Execution Mode" with some fixed values as "*Interactive","*Excel", "*SubreportA", ... so I can control it's behavior in all situations, for instance, when you export to excel, you what to hide some elements in the report so it doesn't create those funny merged cells which are anyone's nightmare when trying to filter or order a list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I do this? I've made the header in my subreport, but not sure how to set up the parameter to make it so that it will show the header. I thought that main report always overrides subreport headers, how do I get it to ignore this?

Comment: Ok, now I understand in what regard we're not aligned. When I talk about report header (in my prior answer) I mean an panel int the top of the body, because I don't usually use the report header itself. This is because when you want a report header containing dynamic values based on the content, you need to do that within the body. Once you have your custom "header" in the body, you can modify the visibility of the component using a value of any parameter.